# Microsoft Azure Devops Override Network driver when container job is initializing

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines

I encountered an issue and not sure any of you encountered before. I tried to start a container job in which Linux based hosted on Window Server 2019. The hosted machine has docker EE installed and was able to run the container.

However, when I tried to trigger the Azure Pipeline to run the job in the the self-hosted machine, it shows following error:

[Failed to create network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWRju.png)

It appears that the agent failed to create the network using the default driver (Bridge) before starting up the container as the self-hosting server is Windows Server - windows uses NAT driver whereas the default driver for Docker is Bridge driver.

I wonder is it possible to override the driver using NAT driver in azure-pipeline? I tried using the following method but it seemed like not able to override it.

[azure-pipelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdalD.png)

Or, is there any alternative way to disable the agent to create the network before starting the docker?

Or, is there any alternative to run Linux container in Windows Server?

Comment: Please add the content of the images as text